# Nginx password protected directory not working for deeper links

Tags: nginx, passwords, nginx-location

I have an Nginx password protected directory that works just fine if you go to mydomain.com/protected_folder/. However if I go to mydomain.com/protected_folder/index.php the page loads up just fine... and it shouldn't.

How do I set up my location block to completely block all access past the protected directory?

My block:

```
location /protected_folder {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        auth_basic "Protected Folder Login";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/my_pass;
         }
```

As a side note. When I had the whole site password protected this was not an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `.php` files are not processed by this location block. They are processed by a location block such as `location ~ \.php$`.

If you use the `^~` modifier, you will force this location block to have a higher precedence than the regular expression location block. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

This will of course prevent `//mydomain.com/protected_folder/index.php` from executing correctly. To correct this, you will need a nested `location ~ \.php$` block to handle `.php` files under the `/protected_folder`.

For example:

```
root /path/to/root;

location ^~ /protected_folder {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    auth_basic "Protected Folder Login";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/my_pass;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        ...
    }
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    ...
}
```

The nested `location ~ \.php$` block is a duplicate of the existing `location ~ \.php$` block within the `server` block.

Comment: Thanks Richard, that seems to have done the trick. Thanks a million!